# Wrong Bootstrap appearance in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I've developed a Bootstrap application and it looks perfect in the local environment, but on a server, in Internet Explorer, it seems like it's in a smaller size device, like a tablet.

**Local:**

[image]

**Server:**

[image]

Comment: Check for compatibility mode and/or quirks mode.

Comment: I tried it but the problem persists.
Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following, download `respond.min.js`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<script src="js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```